# Android master detail detail

Tags: android, master-detail

I'm having a problem coming back from a detail page to its parent. The problem is that it's three levels and the issue is coming from the third level back to the second level.
Imagine a list of invoices. Tap on one of them and it loads the detail of the invoice with the list of line items in the invoice. Tap on a line item and it goes to a third activity with the details for that line item. The line item is launched via tap response like so...

**[EDIT Added manifest info]**

```
<activity
    android:name=".InvocieListActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".InvoiceDetailActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_invoice_detail"
    android:parentActivityName=".InvoiceListActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.myweb.ree.InvocieListActivity"/>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".InvoiceItemDetailActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_invoiceitem_detail"
    android:parentActivityName=".InvoiceDetailActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.myweb.ree.InvoiceDetailActivity"/>
</activity>

private BroadcastReceiver invoiceItemReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_INVOICEITEM_TAPPED)) {
            String invoiceItemId = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.MSG_DATA);
            if (invoiceItemId != null && invoiceItemId.length() > 0) {
                launchInvoiceItemActivity(invoiceItemId);
            }
        }
    }
};

private void launchInvoiceItemActivity(String invoiceItemId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InvoiceItemDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ARG_InvoiceItem_ID, invoiceItemId);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

The invoice detail has the `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` so that it can return to the list of invoices. The line item detail page has the same line to allow the back button to go to the invoice.

When I tap the back button on the line item detail activity it can't load the invoice because it doesn't have the invoice number that was passed in from the original list.

I understand I can override onBackPressed and create an intent that launches its parent rather than letting the framework do it. My question is will that mess up any internal view stack that the framework is keeping in the case of parent-child navigation? Is there some other way that I'm supposed to track items in a master view so it can be reloaded with the correct content when returning from a detail view?

TIA
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code snippet and the description, i can understand that the back stack will be like

InvoiceListActivity -> InvoiceDetailsActivity -> InvoiceItemDetailActivity.

Now override onOptionsItemSelected method in each of child activity.

Eg: in InvoiceItemDetailActivity class, override the method as shown below.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
   // this will finish the current activity. and as the activity behind this in the back stack is InvoiceDetailsActivity, the same will just be resumed.
        finish();
        return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

The same can be done in InvoiceDetailsActivity as well. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's looks like your 2nd Activity getting destroyed. That is why when you go back new instance doesn't have invoice number. To solve this problem you could save 2nd Activity state (invoice number etc) by overrding [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)). Then you could save your 2nd activity state and restore it when goes back from 3rd.

Also you could save invoice number into [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). But you need to update it's value each time you launch this Activity with different invoice number to keep consistency. You could do this in `onCreate()` or/and in `onNewIntent()` depending of `Activity` configurations. And read this value in `onResume()`.

Comment: j2ko Is it typical in a master-detail navigation that the master activity is destroyed while displaying the detail page? I'm more familiar with iOS where the detail page is loaded on top of the master page.
I don't have an issue with doing the navigation back to level 2 manually and passing the second level id back. I suppose if level 2 is getting destroyed then I couldn't be interfering with a navigation stack.

Comment: It's depends. Android decide when to destroy an Activity (Memory issue or some other reasons). But It keep the stack in tact so when you go back it will recreate it. If you will try to manually control the navigation this will lead to total mess. Sure you could go with it but amount of possible bugs is huge. As an additional benefit from implementing `onSaveInstanceState` would be support of rotation and other configuration changes that will recreate activity.

Comment: I saved the invoiceId state but when it returns from the detail it enters via onCreate, savedInstanceState is null, and it doesn't run the onRestoreInstanceState (does not stop at my breakpoint). I edited the original to include the code used to launch the detail just in case that makes a difference.

Comment: What is purpose of using broadcast receiver? To help you I need to know how 2nd and 3rd activity declared in AndroidManifest, and how you launch 2nd activity and 3rd activity. As I undertand BroadcastReceiver launches 3rd Activity, right?

Comment: Ah, yeah. OK The list of items can be used in multiple places so the list doesn't know what is supposed to be done with the item that was tapped. It just announces that something was tapped and which one it was. The activity that's using it will decide what to do. That's why it uses a broadcast receiver. I'll add manifest items to the post.